# Using pool.scalar() for multivariate analysis to pool data after multiple imputation

Tags: imputation, r-mice, mediator

My study aims to examine multiple parallel mediators between a predictor and an outcome variable. I've used `mice` to run multiple imputations for the missing data. I would like to use the `PROCESS` function in `bruceR` package to conduct the multiple mediation.

Upon checking the relevant discussions, I understand that `bruceR` is not incorporated into `broom` so I received error messages after using the `mice::pool` function.

I also understand that I can use `pool.scalar()` function to extract the analysis myself. However, I can only find instructions for using `pool.scalar()` for [univariate analysis](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mice/versions/3.16.0/topics/pool.scalar). Since my analysis involves multiple mediators (5 in total), can anyone please advise on the steps for multivariate analysis or direct me to the resources on this? I'm afraid I can't find the relevant guidance online...

Answer (score 0):

There's now a new function in `mice` (v3.16.0) to pool estimates of analyses that are not recognized by the `broom` workflow underlying the `pool()` function. See the `pool.table()` documentation on https://amices.org/mice/reference/pool.table.

```
# conventional mice workflow
imp <- mice(nhanes2, m = 2, maxit = 2, seed = 1, print = FALSE)
fit <- with(imp, lm(chl ~ age + bmi + hyp))
pld1 <- pool(fit)
pld1$pooled

# using pool.table() on tidy table
tbl <- summary(fit)[, c("term", "estimate", "std.error", "df.residual")]
tbl
pld2 <- pool.table(tbl, type = "minimal")
pld2

identical(pld1$pooled, pld2)

# conventional workflow: all numerical output
all1 <- summary(pld1, type = "all", conf.int = TRUE)
all1

# pool.table workflow: all numerical output
all2 <- pool.table(tbl)
all2

identical(data.frame(all1), all2)
```